# Reorder queue in Java's ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Java Executors: how can I set task priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198660/java-executors-how-can-i-set-task-priority)

I have a ThreadPoolExecutor built using a LinkedBlockingDequeue and I want to manipulate the underlying queue, however reading this in the documentation makes me very nervous.

> Queue maintenance
>
> Method getQueue() allows access to the work queue for purposes of monitoring and debugging. Use of this method for any other purpose is strongly discouraged. Two supplied methods, remove(java.lang.Runnable) and purge() are available to assist in storage reclamation when large numbers of queued tasks become cancelled.

Specifically I want to be able to

1. Check the queue to see if an element already exists.  I assume this is fine as no locking should be necessary to just view the elements in the queue.
2. I want to reorder the queue based on some signal.  This can obviously be troublesome.  I was wondering if there is a preferred way to do this so that I won't mess up the queue for other uses.

Thanks

Comment: As the documentation notes, you should not be controlling the queue from that method. You should be controlling it from the queue that you passed in to your `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: But doesn't that still run the risk of threading problems?  I thought if I call getQueue() that's the same as modifying the actual queue object I pass in.

Comment: I don't think I can use a PriorityComparator as suggested in the other question because PriorityComparator provides no way to reorder elements once they are in the queue.

Comment: It will as long as you `remove` and then re-`add` the `Runnable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getQueue()` will always return the exact `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` that you pass into the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

The worry with the documentation is that you could easily run into issues with double-running if you cannot guarantee the thread safety of the `BlockingQueue`. If you use a `PriorityBlockingQueue`, and only use `remove` and `add` (or, more directly, `offer`), then you will be safe, and you can even do it directly from the `getQueue()`.

In other words, whenever your signal tells you that some `Runnable`'s priority has changed, then you should `remove` it and check the result of the remove (`true` if removed), and only if it was actually removed, then you should re-add it. You are not guaranteed that something won't be picked up inbetween those operations, but you are at least guaranteed that you will not double-run the `Runnable`, which could easily happen if done with `contains` -> `remove` -> `add`.

Either that, or you can write your own implementation of a `BlockingQueue` that uses a `Comparator` (like the `PriorityBlockingQueue`) that finds the highest priority whenever asked for new data. This sounds like a lot more work given the various interfaces involved.