# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor: How to priorize Tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduledexecutorservice

I need an ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor that runs Task according there priority. If 2 or more Task a pending for immediate execution the one with the highest priority must be called first.

Actually there is a solution for ThreadPoolExecutor, but not for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, cause it provides no constructor with a BlockingQueue argument.

See: [Java Executors: how can I set task priority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198660/java-executors-how-can-i-set-task-priority)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'll have a single threaded `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which posts to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a `PriorityBlockingQueue`. Not the most elegant, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: How would you implement the methods like scheduleXXX(..) that are not part of ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: @Chriss: What I meant is, do use a scheduled executor, but let it simply post (submit the task) to a thread pool executor with priority queue. This way, you can do everything you can do with a scheduled executor and still have prioritized execution in effect

Comment: Downside is (potentially) a tiny loss in performance/scheduling accuracy but I'm most certain it'd be too small matter