# Java thread pool blocking queue, execute always last few

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have several tasks that are being created by some event. I want to execute the last few tasks(suppose 6) always.

I am using a fixed thread pool. But the problem I am facing is that, it uses a blocking queue internally. I want to dequeue the tasks from the blocking queue if there are new tasks coming in, without pushing them to the executor. How can I achieve this? Is there a different approach to this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of [Java Executors: how can I set task priority?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198660/java-executors-how-can-i-set-task-priority) - Set a higher priority on the new tasks and the executor will run those first. You'll need to define what attribute/s to use as a priority.

Comment: @Augusto I also want to remove the old tasks with low priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you want, you can use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. And set the flag `setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true)`.

This executor returns a `Future` when you call the `submit` methods. These futures have a `cancel()` method that you can call when the new request comes in. You can even cancel the tasks that are currently running if you want too.

There's another alternative to call `ThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue().clear()`, but this is not safe! So please don't try it :)