# A priority based custom Executor in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring 5 and Java 8 and after suggestions on how to implement an Executor service in Spring that I can submit tasks to from a REST controller and have them queued and executed in "priority" order, not the submit order? That is, the tasks implement Runnable and Comparable and get queued and executed according to the natural ordering of the tasks. I'm sure there must be a simple solution and pattern in Spring for this but I'm struggling to find one.

Comment: suggestions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198660/java-executors-how-can-i-set-task-priority

Comment: I have been searching for a day and bit but not seen that thread. Thanks Sean, it looks like good info.