# How to set the relative priority of scheduled thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got two scheduled tasks. One has the higher priority : its scheduling must be respected the best. The second one has a lower priority : the performances may more impact its scheduling.

In ThreadGroup we can the Priority. But I don't find how to this with Executors.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService serviceProduce = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

// May be delayed by performance
serviceProduce.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ComputeThread(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// Should be kept as much as possible on schedule
serviceProduce.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ProduceOutputThread(), 0, 30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: May be this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3198953/7386743

Comment: This answer was not the one. But another later on the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869396/2398993. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I solved it:

```
ThreadGroup threadGroupCompute = new ThreadGroup("compute");
threadGroupCompute.setMaxPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
threadGroupCompute.setDaemon(false);
ThreadFactory threadFacoryCompute = new ThreadFactory() {
    long cnt = 0;
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(threadGroupCompute, r, "thread-" + threadGroupCompute.getName() + "-" + cnt++);
        return t;
    }
};
final ScheduledExecutorService executorCompute = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, threadFacoryCompute);

// May be delayed by performance
executorCompute .scheduleAtFixedRate(new ComputeThread(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

And this 2 times. One with a ThreadGroup with priority set to `Thread.NORM_PRIORITY`, one with priority set to `Thread.MAX_PRIORITY`