# How to set @Async methods thread priority - spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have this async method in Spring Boot:

```java
@Async
public void calculateResult(List matrix) {
    //do calculation
}
```

This method is invoked at the controller.

I want to reduce the priority of this calculation method threads. How do I do that?

Comment: u need custom taskExecutor. using async u can not set priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With async anotation u can not acheive this. `@Async` take only custom task executor.. No way to set priority. But u can do it manualy like this:

Create this bean:

```
@Bean("CustomTaskExecutor")
  public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor(
          @Value("${spring.async.core-pool-size}") int corePoolSize,
          @Value("${spring.async.max-pool-size}") int maxPoolSize,
          @Value("${spring.async.queue-capacity}") int queueCapacity) {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {

      @Override
      protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
        return new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueCapacity);
      }

    };
    executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
    return executor;
  }
```

Task with priorities:

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    private Consumer<Job> jobConsumer;
    private Job job;
      public Job getJob() {
        return this.job;
      }
      public Task(Consumer<Job> jobConsumer, Job job) {
        this.jobConsumer = jobConsumer;
        this.job = job;
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
        this.jobConsumer.accept(job);
      }
    }
```

Future custom task:

```
public class FutureCustomTask extends FutureTask<FutureCustomTask> implements Comparable<FutureCustomTask> {
private Task task;
public FutureCustomTask(Task task) {
    super(task, null);
    this.task = task;
  }
@Override
  public int compareTo(FutureCustomTask o) {
    return task.getJob().getPriority().compareTo(o.task.getJob().getPriority());
  }
}
```

Finaly set priority like this:

```
@Autowired
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
@Autowired
private JobBusiness jobBusiness;
...
Task task = new Task(jobBusiness::performSomethingOn, job);
taskExecutor.execute(new FutureCustomTask(task));
```

I took this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977971/6831257)

Look at [this](https://medium.com/@daniyaryeralin/priority-based-thread-pooling-in-spring-framework-d74b91b51dcb) tutorial also....