# How to implement PriorityBlockingQueue with ThreadPoolExecutor and custom tasks

Tags: java, threadpool, priority-queue, executor, futuretask

I've searched a lot but could not find a solutuion to my problem.

I have my own class, `BaseTask`, that uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to handle tasks.  I want task prioritization, but when I try to use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` I get `ClassCastException` because the `ThreadPoolExecutor` wraps my Tasks into a `FutureTask` object.

This obviously makes sense because the `FutureTask` does not implement `Comparable`, but how would I go on to solve the priority problem?   I've read that you could override `newTaskFor()` in `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but I can not seem to find this method at all...?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

**Some code to help:**

In my `BaseTask` class I have

```
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sWorkQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
    }
};

private static final BaseThreadPoolExecutor sExecutor = new BaseThreadPoolExecutor(
    1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);

private final BaseFutureTask<Result> mFuture;

public BaseTask(int priority) {
    mFuture = new BaseFutureTask<Result>(mWorker, priority);
}

public final BaseTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {

    /* Some unimportant code here */

    sExecutor.execute(mFuture);
}
```

In `BaseFutureTask` class

```
@Override
public int compareTo(BaseFutureTask another) {
    long diff = this.priority - another.priority;

    return Long.signum(diff);
}
```

In `BaseThreadPoolExecutor` class i override the 3 `submit` methods...  The constructor in this class gets called, but none of the `submit` methods

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807223/how-do-i-implement-task-prioritization-using-an-executorservice-in-java-5

Comment: The thread the OP refers to is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430574/how-to-have-an-unbound-sortable-queue-utilized-by-a-fixed-amount-of-threads/12663571#12663571

Answer (score 14):

```
public class ExecutorPriority {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> pq = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20, new ComparePriority());

    Executor exe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 2, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, pq);
    exe.execute(new RunWithPriority(2) {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println(this.getPriority() + " started");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ExecutorPriority.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(this.getPriority() + " finished");
        }
    });
    exe.execute(new RunWithPriority(10) {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(this.getPriority() + " started");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ExecutorPriority.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(this.getPriority() + " finished");
        }
    });

}

private static class ComparePriority<T extends RunWithPriority> implements Comparator<T> {

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.getPriority().compareTo(o2.getPriority());
    }
}
```

}

as you can guess RunWithPriority is an abstract class that is Runnable and has a Integer priority field

Comment: I really don't understand your example! Am I stupid or the first `Executor ex` is never used? lol

Comment: I don't see why this is the most upvoted answer. `new ComparePriority()` is not specifying the generic type parameter, so I consider this a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can use these helper classes:

```
public class PriorityFuture<T> implements RunnableFuture<T> {

    private RunnableFuture<T> src;
    private int priority;

    public PriorityFuture(RunnableFuture<T> other, int priority) {
        this.src = other;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        return src.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
    }

    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return src.isCancelled();
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return src.isDone();
    }

    public T get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return src.get();
    }

    public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        return src.get();
    }

    public void run() {
        src.run();
    }

    public static Comparator<Runnable> COMP = new Comparator<Runnable>() {
        public int compare(Runnable o1, Runnable o2) {
            if (o1 == null && o2 == null)
                return 0;
            else if (o1 == null)
                return -1;
            else if (o2 == null)
                return 1;
            else {
                int p1 = ((PriorityFuture<?>) o1).getPriority();
                int p2 = ((PriorityFuture<?>) o2).getPriority();

                return p1 > p2 ? 1 : (p1 == p2 ? 0 : -1);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**AND**

```
public interface PriorityCallable<T> extends Callable<T> {

    int getPriority();

}
```

**AND** this helper method:

```
public static ThreadPoolExecutor getPriorityExecutor(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10, PriorityFuture.COMP)) {

        protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
            RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor = super.newTaskFor(callable);
            return new PriorityFuture<T>(newTaskFor, ((PriorityCallable<T>) callable).getPriority());
        }
    };
}
```

**AND** then use it like this:

```
class LenthyJob implements PriorityCallable<Long> {
    private int priority;

    public LenthyJob(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public Long call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Executing: " + priority);
        long num = 1000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            num *= Math.random() * 1000;
            num /= Math.random() * 1000;
            if (num == 0)
                num = 1000000;
        }
        return num;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}

public class TestPQ {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor exec = getPriorityExecutor(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int priority = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.println("Scheduling: " + priority);
            LenthyJob job = new LenthyJob(priority);
            exec.submit(job);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Thanks @Stanislav.

Answer (score 5):

I will try to explain this problem with a fully functional code. But before diving into the code I would like to explain about PriorityBlockingQueue

**PriorityBlockingQueue** : PriorityBlockingQueue is an implementation of BlockingQueue. It accepts the tasks along with their priority and submits the task with the highest priority for execution first. If any two tasks have same priority, then we need to provide some custom logic to decide which task goes first.

Now lets get into the code straightaway.

**Driver class** : This class creates an executor which accepts tasks and later submits them for execution. Here we create two tasks one with LOW priority and the other with HIGH priority. Here we tell the executor to run a MAX  of 1 threads and use the PriorityBlockingQueue.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

       /*
       Minimum number of threads that must be running : 0
       Maximium number of threads that can be created : 1
       If a thread is idle, then the minimum time to keep it alive : 1000
       Which queue to use : PriorityBlockingQueue
       */
    PriorityBlockingQueue queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue();
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0,1,
        1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,queue);

    MyTask task = new MyTask(Priority.LOW,"Low");
    executor.execute(new MyFutureTask(task));
    task = new MyTask(Priority.HIGH,"High");
    executor.execute(new MyFutureTask(task));
}
```

**MyTask class** : MyTask implements Runnable and accepts priority as an argument in the constructor. When this task runs, it prints a message and then puts the thread to sleep for 1 second.

```
   public class MyTask implements Runnable {

  public int getPriority() {
    return priority.getValue();
  }

  private Priority priority;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  private String name;

  public MyTask(Priority priority,String name){
    this.priority = priority;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("The following Runnable is getting executed "+getName());
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

**MyFutureTask class** : Since we are using PriorityBlocingQueue for holding our tasks, our tasks must be wrapped inside FutureTask and our implementation of FutureTask must implement Comparable interface. The Comparable interface compares the priority of 2 different tasks and submits the task with the highest priority for execution.

```
 public class MyFutureTask extends FutureTask<MyFutureTask>
      implements Comparable<MyFutureTask> {

    private  MyTask task = null;

    public  MyFutureTask(MyTask task){
      super(task,null);
      this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyFutureTask another) {
      return task.getPriority() - another.task.getPriority();
    }
  }
```

**Priority class** : Self explanatory Priority class.

```
public enum Priority {

  HIGHEST(0),
  HIGH(1),
  MEDIUM(2),
  LOW(3),
  LOWEST(4);

  int value;

  Priority(int val) {
    this.value = val;
  }

  public int getValue(){
    return value;
  }


}
```

Now when we run this example, we get the following output

```
The following Runnable is getting executed High
The following Runnable is getting executed Low
```

Even though we submitted the LOW priority first, but HIGH priority task later, but since we are using a PriorityBlockingQueue, an task with a higher priority will execute first.

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
public class XThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor
{
    public XThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
        long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)
    {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    public XThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
        long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
        RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
    {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, handler);
    }

    public XThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
        long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
        ThreadFactory threadFactory)
    {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory);
    }

    public XThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
        long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
        ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
    {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value)
    {
        return new ComparableFutureTask<>(runnable, value);
    }

    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable)
    {
        return new ComparableFutureTask<>(callable);
    }

    protected class ComparableFutureTask<V>
        extends FutureTask<V> implements Comparable<ComparableFutureTask<V>>
    {
        private Object object;
        public ComparableFutureTask(Callable<V> callable)
        {
            super(callable);
            object = callable;
        }

        public ComparableFutureTask(Runnable runnable, V result)
        {
            super(runnable, result);
            object = runnable;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public int compareTo(ComparableFutureTask<V> o)
        {
            if (this == o)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (o == null)
            {
                return -1; // high priority
            }
            if (object != null && o.object != null)
            {
                if (object.getClass().equals(o.object.getClass()))
                {
                    if (object instanceof Comparable)
                    {
                        return ((Comparable) object).compareTo(o.object);
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they left that out of apache harmony. There is a [svn commit log](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/harmony-commits/200908.mbox/%3C20090803142226.0191D23888A2@eris.apache.org%3E) about a year ago fixing the absence of `newTaskFor`. You can probably just override the `submit` functions in an extended `ThreadPoolExecutor` to create an extended `FutureTask` that is `Comparable`. [They are not very long](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob;f=libcore/concurrent/src/main/java/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.java;h=f7ed15cc320ac2419a76fc71a8ef576a967872bc;hb=ba7e99a13ccb03611781cfec2631303cc042c76a).

Comment: No, you have to extend it. It gets wrapped in a FutureTask in the various submit methods.

Comment: It doesn't seem like any of the `submit` methods gets called...  Added some code to help understand

Comment: Don't call `ThreadPoolExecutor#execute` anymore. Anything you want to have done by the thread pool will need to go in via a `submit` call. The `submit` methods should then call `execute` for you.

Comment: But the only thing the `submit` method does is just that, call the `execute` method... It creates a new `BaseFutureTask` and then executes it

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: The `newTaskFor()` method is found in `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s superclass, `AbstractExecutorService`. You can simply override it in `ThreadPoolExecutor`, however.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a simplified version of @StanislavVitvitskyy's answer.  Thanks to him.

I wanted to make the *jobs* that I submitted be `Comparable`.  I created an `ExecutorService` with a `PriorityBlockingQueue` and extend it to handle the `newTaskFor(...)` methods:

```
ExecutorService pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize,
    keepAliveTime, timeUnit, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>()) {

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
        return new ComparableFutureTask<T>(runnable, value);
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new ComparableFutureTask<T>(callable);
    };
};
```

I defined a `ComparableFutureTask` which extends `FutureTask` and implements `Comparable` by delegating to the `job.compareTo(...)` that are submitted to the pool.

```
public class ComparableFutureTask<T> extends FutureTask<T>
    implements Comparable<Object> {

    private final Comparable<Object> comparableJob;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ComparableFutureTask(Runnable runnable, T value) {
        super(runnable, value);
        this.comparableJob = (Comparable<Object>) runnable;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ComparableFutureTask(Callable<T> callable) {
        super(callable);
        this.comparableJob = (Comparable<Object>) callable;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return this.comparableJob
            .compareTo(((ComparableFutureTask<?>) o).comparable);
    }
}
```

This `ExecutorService` then can handle `Runnable` or `Callable` jobs that are also `Comparable`.  For example:

```
public class MyJob implements Runnable, Comparable<MyJob> {
    private int priority;
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyJob other) {
        // we want higher priority to go first
        return other.priority - this.priority;
    }
    ...
}
```

It is important to note that if you submit a job that is not `Comparable` to this queue, it will throw a `ClassCastException`.