# How to have an unbound sortable queue utilized by a fixed amount of threads?

Tags: java, threadpool, priority-queue

Please assume the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 5, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    DashboardHtmlExport d = new DashboardHtmlExport();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        System.out.println("Submitting: " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(cooldown);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pool.submit(d.new A(i));
    }
}

private class A implements Runnable, Comparable<A> {
    private int order;

    public A(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(busyTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }

    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o.order).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(order));
    }
}
```

This produced the following error:

```
Submitting: 0
Submitting: 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:578)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:574)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:653)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:78)
    at com.skycomm.cth.pages.test.DashboardHtmlExport.main(DashboardHtmlExport.java:133)
Tue Jul 10 23:48:45 GMT+02:00 2012
```

Why is this happening ?!

This only works if the `busyTime` is **less** that the `cooldown` time. Meaning that the queue can't handle more than 2 submitted tasks !!

Basically what I'm trying to do is to have a pool with **UNBOUND** size and sortable whether by comparable or a comparator. I can only achieve an **UNBOUND** queue using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` but that's of course not sortable !

Thank you.

Comment: The class `A` is in an inner class, inside `DashboardHtmlExport`. So I need a `DashboardHtmlExport` instance to call `new A(i)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ThreadPoolExecutor transforms the Runnable you submit into a `RunnableFuture` using the [newTaskFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor%28java.lang.Runnable,%20T%29) method, and adds this RunnableFuture to the queue. So if you want to use a PriorityQueue, you should override the `newTaskFor()` method to make sure the `RunnableFuture` instances it creates are comparable.

Or you could also use the `execute()` method instead of the `submit()` method, to bypass the task creation.

Comment: Thank you. But why does it work for the first 2 submissions only ?! Also if the `cooldown` is more than the `busyTime`, it works !

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana:If you never have more than one object in the queue, no comparison is made, and you don't get the error. So you need to produce them faster than you consume them for this error to occur.

Comment: Probably because the queue doesn't have to do any comparison in these situations, because it's empty when the task is added to the queue.