# implementing PriorityQueue on ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, priority-queue, future, threadpoolexecutor

Been struggling with this for over 2 days now.

implemented the answer I saw on here 
[Specify task order execution in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722396/specify-task-order-execution-in-java/12722648#12722648)

```
public class PriorityExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

public PriorityExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
                        long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
}
//Utitlity method to create thread pool easily
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new PriorityExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
//Submit with New comparable task
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task, int priority) {
    return super.submit(new ComparableFutureTask(task, null, priority));
}
//execute with New comparable task
public void execute(Runnable command, int priority) {
    super.execute(new ComparableFutureTask(command, null, priority));
}
}

public class ComparableFutureTask<T> extends FutureTask<T>
    implements
    Comparable<ComparableFutureTask<T>> {

volatile int priority = 0;

public ComparableFutureTask(Runnable runnable, T result, int priority) {
    super(runnable, result);
    this.priority = priority;
}
public ComparableFutureTask(Callable<T> callable, int priority) {
    super(callable);
    this.priority = priority;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ComparableFutureTask<T> o) {
    return Integer.valueOf(priority).compareTo(o.priority);
}
}
```

The Runnable I use: MyTask

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable{

 public MyTask(File file, Context context, int requestId) {
    this._file = file;
    this.context = context;
    this.requestId = requestId;
}

@Override
public void run() {
      // some work
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Callable try", post.toString());

    }
}
```

My service: MediaDownloadService

```
public class MediaDownloadService extends Service {

private DBHelper helper;
Notification notification;
HashMap<Integer,Future> futureTasks = new HashMap<Integer, Future>();
final int _notificationId=1;
File file;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return sharonsBinder;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    helper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    PriorityExecutor executor = (PriorityExecutor) PriorityExecutor.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Log.e("requestsExists", helper.requestsExists() + "");
   if(helper.requestsExists()){
        // map of the index of the request and the string of the absolute path of the request
        Map<Integer,String> requestMap = helper.getRequestsToExcute(0);
        Set<Integer> keySet = requestMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = keySet.iterator();
        Log.e("MAP",requestMap.toString());
        //checks if the DB requests exists
        if(!requestMap.isEmpty()){
            //execute them and delete the DB entry
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                int iteratorNext = iterator.next();
                Log.e("ITREATOR", iteratorNext + "");
                file = new File(requestMap.get(iteratorNext));
                Log.e("file", file.toString());
                Log.e("thread Opened", "Thread" + iteratorNext);
                Future future = executor.submit(new MyTask(file, this, iteratorNext),10);
                futureTasks.put(iteratorNext, future);
                helper.requestTaken(iteratorNext);
            }
            Log.e("The priority queue",executor.getQueue().toString());
        }else{

            Log.e("stopself", "stop self after this");
            this.stopSelf();
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

keep getting an error on this line :
Future future = executor.submit(new MyTask(file, this, iteratorNext),10);

Even tho an executor.submit(); suppose to return a future object i keep getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
        at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:450)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1331)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:81)
        at com.vit.infibond.test.PriorityExecutor.submit(PriorityExecutor.java:26)
        at com.vit.infibond.test.MediaDownloadService.onStartCommand(MediaDownloadService.java:65)
```

Can anyone save me from this nightmare?

I tried doing as this answer suggest as well
[Testing PriorityBlockingQueue in ThreadPoolExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833951/testing-priorityblockingqueue-in-threadpoolexecutor/16834473#16834473)

by adding the forNewTask override only to get casting execption again but this time for RunnableFuture.

I understand something basic is missing on my understanding and would appreciate a depth explanation...

Comment: Thanks sharon, I have extended on your comments below. rather an intense topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the source code for `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` it seems to be a real pain to get this working when submitting futures. You have to override protected methods that feels internal and do some nasty casts.

I suggest you simply use the `execute` method instead. There is no wrapping of the `Runnable` going on there so it should work.

If you need to wait for the results of your jobs I suggest implementing that on your own to avoid having to mess around with the `ThreadPoolExecutor` internals.

Comment: My problem is not waiting for my jobs to complete but I want to mange them as they are in queue.

For example i got items on queue and i need right now to improve one of their priorities, so i need to have a reference to that future object so i can cancel that task and reinsert it with an higher priority.

And ill appreciate if explain a bit more about implementing it on my own, you mean to create a thread pool by myself?

Comment: To change the priority you need access to the `ComparableFutureTask` since that is what is on the queue, not the `Future`. Hence, for that purpose you can still use the `executor.execute()` instead of `submit()`.

Comment: executor.execute() will return a ComparableFutureTask? If not how will I reach the task I want to cancel..? I thought that to change priority I must cancel and reinsert the task, and cancel is done through the future object.. or is it?

Comment: @sharongur No it doesn't, but since you have implemented the PriorityExecutor you can make a custom method to return it when executing.

Comment: Brilliant! Absolutley brilliant!
I changed the execute method to return a ComparableFutureTask and added a method to increase priority with an id for my hashmap that contains the Comparable objects, then just change its priority
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

What sharon gur has suggest at the very bottom is to change

```
//execute with New comparable task
public void execute(Runnable command, int priority) {
    super.execute(new ComparableFutureTask(command, null, priority));
}
```

to

```
//execute with New comparable task
public ComparableFutureTask  execute(Runnable command, int priority) {
    ComparableFutureTask task = new ComparableFutureTask(command, null, priority);
    super.execute(task);
    return task;
}
```

Then in your caller:

```
CurrentTask currentTask = new CurrentTask(priority,queue)
RunnableFuture task = enhancedExecutor.execute(currentTask,priority.value)
task?.get()
```

I had a problem where

```
RunnableFuture task = myExecutor.submit(currentTask)
task?.get()
```

caused an issue where `currentTask` was then converted to `FutureTask` and had no understanding of my objects within CurrentTask. As `.execute` alone everything was fine. This hack appears to semi / near enough work.

so as it worked perfectly but no file was produced

```
RunnableFuture task = myExecutor.execuute(currentTask)
    task?.get()
```

So this is how I made it work  (priority is being handled twice) doesn't feel right but works...

CurrentTask::

```
class CurrentTask implements Runnable {
    private Priority priority
    private MyQueue queue

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority.value
    }

    public CurrentTask(Priority priority,ReportsQueue queue){
        this.priority = priority
        this.queue=queue
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
...
}
}
```

Priority:

```
public enum Priority {

    HIGHEST(0),
    HIGH(1),
    MEDIUM(2),
    LOW(3),
    LOWEST(4)

    int value

    Priority(int val) {
        this.value = val
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value
    }
}
```

Then your executor call

```
public YourExecutor() {

    public YourExecutor() {
        super(maxPoolSize,maxPoolSize,timeout,TimeUnit.SECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000,new ReverseComparator()))
    }
```

So before changing to new method submit hit the comparator below and  being TaskExecutor would not understand .priority?.value which as default .execute currentTask was what hit this and it all worked

```
public int compare(final Runnable lhs, final Runnable rhs) {

    if(lhs instanceof Runnable && rhs instanceof Runnable){
      // Favour a higher priority
        println "${lhs} vs ${lhs.getClass()}"
      if(((Runnable)lhs)?.priority?.value<((Runnable)rhs)?.priority?.value){
 ...
}

}
```

so with above hack and below changes it appears to be working

```
class  ReverseComparator implements Comparator<ComparableFutureTask>{

  @Override
  public int compare(final ComparableFutureTask lhs, final ComparableFutureTask rhs) {

    if(lhs instanceof ComparableFutureTask && rhs instanceof ComparableFutureTask){

        // run higher priority (lower numbers before higher numbers)
        println "${lhs} vs ${lhs.getClass()} ::: ${lhs.priority}"
      if(((Runnable)lhs)?.priority<((Runnable)rhs)?.priority){
          println "-returning -1"
        return -1;
      } else if (((Runnable)lhs)?.priority>((Runnable)rhs)?.priority){
      println "-returning @@@1"
        return 1;
      } 


    }
    println "-returning ==0 "
    return 0;
  }
```

Simply because we have passed in override `ComparableFutureTask` that has a priority which extends `FutureTask`

Hope it makes sense been going round for a day and a bit now :)

Comment: working implementation can be found here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin