# cancel() vs remove() on executors

Tags: java, future, threadpoolexecutor

Recently I worked with ThreadPoolExecutor and priorityqueue and came across both methods future.cancel() on a future task. 
And task.remove() on the task it self, to remove it from the queue.

What is the better option? is there any difference? I can save list of both (the future object received from submit() or the tasks themselves), not sure what to use...

remove:

```
executor.remove(task);
executor.purge();
```

cancel:

```
futureObject.cancel(false);
```

I used the following:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#remove%28java.lang.Runnable%29

The false in the cancel is because I only want to remove a queue task, if it runs, let it finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Future.cancel()`

The Javadoc for `ThreadPoolExecutor.remove()` states that it may "fail to remove tasks that have been converted into other forms before being placed on the internal queue", so I wouldn't recommend calling it unless you are sure the task wasn't converted internally.

Given that, if you have a `Future`,  I would recommend canceling it by calling `Future.cancel()`. This has the added advantage of doing the right thing if someone else has a reference to the `Future` and decides to call `Future.get()`

If you are paranoid about the amount of heap used by the cancelled tasks, you can call `ThreadPoolExecutor.purge()` after calling `Future.cancel()`.

By the way, the `ThreadPoolExecutor.purge()` method only removes Futures that have been canceled, so calling `purge()` after `remove()` is likely a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the one which is more natural for you.  Without further information that is most likely the `cancel`

`remove/purge` is much more expensive and only really needed if you are concerned you will have so many of these tasks they might be using too much memory.

The difference is pretty self explanatory, cancel just cancels the task.  remove/purge removes the task from the queue.

Comment: I am using a priorityQueue therefore I save a ComparableFutureTask as this suggests:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574777/implementing-priorityqueue-on-threadpoolexecutor
I override the execute to return that ComparabaleFutureTask, and save all the referrences and on this object i preform the cancel(). and for some reason it doesnt work... I assume ill need to open a new question specific to that occurrence but is it suppose to work the same on a comparableFutureTask?
Any

Comment: @sharongur what do you mean by; "it doesn't work" and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I cancel the task and reinsert a new one with higher priority, yet the execution order remains the same. and no new task inserted

Comment: @sharongur so the problem is to do with insertions not cancelling or removing? Ie not related to the question?

Comment: I actually did exactly what the question I posted suggests, but when I added the cancel(); I didn't see any difference to when I didn't initiate that same method. Anyway I didnt investigated that enough to raise another question. Ill try to solved it myself and if I wont find a solution ill turn up here again :) thanks for the help!

Comment: @sharongur cancel just makes the task marked as "cancelled" and it won't run. It does this because this is more efficient than removing it from the data structure. However sometimes you really want it to go away which is why there is an option to remove it, even though it is slower, much slower in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `cancel` to be overridden or your main concern is memory footprint then use `remove/purge`. But in any other case I would go for `cancel`.