# ExecutorService with PriorityBlockingQueue and Implementing Comparator

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, blockingqueue

I am building a REST Service and I have the following structure of classes:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

   @Override
    public void run() {
       //do stuff
    }
}

public class RestController  {

   private MyThreadPool myThreadPool;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<?> getSomething (....){
    myThreadPool.getExecutorService().submit(new MyTask(request));
   }


}


public class MyThreadPool{

    private final static Integer SIZE_OF_POOL = 5;
    private final static Integer KEEP_ALIVE= 5000;
    private final static Integer QUEUE_SIZE = 50;
    private final static Integer MAX_POOL_SIZE = 10;


    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(QUEUE_SIZE); //pass comparator here? 
    private ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(SIZE_OF_POOL, MAX_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue, new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());

    public ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
        return executorService;
    }
}
```

I may have scenarios in my project where my `request` object has an integer to represent **priority**.

I am looking to Submit runnable tasks for execution with this priority value and I am not sure where to implement this logic and how to do it. I know I have to use the `PriorityBlockingQueue` somewhere and implement a `Comparator`. So do I...

1) Implement in MyThreadPool class
2) Or Implement logic in MyTask

Can you guys please show how to implement this Comparator so that requests with highest priority are executed first?

Comment: What is your goal here? To process the request asynchronously? If yes then there are builtin methods to do that.

Comment: The goal is to submit multiple tasks and have the threads process the high priority requests first. The priority is between 1-5 and is part of http GET request uri

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807223/how-do-i-implement-task-prioritization-using-an-executorservice-in-java-5) answer your question?