# java priorityQueue update problem

Tags: java

(sorry for my bad english) I'm writing an implementation of Dijkstra algoritm and I need to use a priority queue.
I use PriorityQueue as definited in Java Platform SE 6.
There is  a way o a method like Q.update() in Java Platform SE 5 that rebuild priority queue in case the priorities of its elements have changed since they were inserted? (I have problem with relax and Q.poll())
I need that the update takes O(log n)

Comment: The point of a priority queue is that the priority of the item shouldn't change. If it does, you should pull it out, and reinsert it with the new priority. What possible requirement do you have that you need a certain bounded runtime? I seriously doubt you'll be able to get O(logN) for rebuilding a queue... You'll be lucky to get O(N)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Java PriorityQueue when its elements change priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871253/updating-java-priorityqueue-when-its-elements-change-priority)

Answer (score 3):

No, with a `PriorityQueue`, there is no way to re-heap elements while they are in the queue.

This is a common optimization for heaps. Although the time complexity of removing the top of the heap and putting an (updated) element back into the heap is of the same order, it takes roughly half the time just to notify the heap that the top element has been updated and may need to be moved down in the heap.

Comment: the problem is that when i have to relax i must remove the element that i want to change priority (weight), update the weight and then readd this element

Comment: Q.remove(v);
            v.setWeight(u.retWeight()+weight);
           
            Q.add(v);

Comment: and i think that Q.remove(v) takes O(n)

Comment: @davy - Yes, I understand the problem. Unfortunately, the built-in `PriorityQueue` doesn't offer a way around it, which is too bad because this is a very common use case for heaps.

Comment: Methods `remove()` and `add()` are both O(log n). Whereas if you just use `peek()` (which is O(1)) and an `update()` (which would be O(log n), it's twice as fast.

Comment: @erickson, for someone coming from c++, it really seems like downgrade. I agree with you, it is too bad that this case is not handled as it is a very common use case for heaps.

Answer (score 3):

Updating the priority of an element already in the priority queue is an important operation and a priority queue not offering this operation is more or less useless.

An implementation of a priority queue which allows **updating an already inserted value in O(log n) time** looks like this:

```
/**
 * PriorityQueue with updatePriority and item concept.
 * Makes use of a min heap.
 * 
 * @author Chris Stamm 
 * @version 6.10.2013
 */

import java.util.*;

public class PQueue<E extends Comparable<E>> {
public static class PQItem<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<PQItem<E>> {
    private E m_data;
    private int m_index;

    public PQItem(E data, int index) {
        m_data = data;
        m_index = index;
    }

    public int compareTo(PQItem<E> item) {
        return m_data.compareTo(item.m_data);
    }

    public E getData() {
        return m_data;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        m_index = index;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return m_index;
    }
}

private ArrayList<PQItem<E>> m_array;

public PQueue() {
    m_array = new ArrayList<PQItem<E>>();
}

/**
 * O(n)
 */
public PQueue(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    m_array = new ArrayList<PQItem<E>>(c.size());

    // copy elements
    int j = 0;
    for(E e: c) {
        m_array.add(new PQItem(e, j++));
    }

    // create heap
    final int s = m_array.size();
    int l2 = s/2 - 1;
    for (int i = l2; i >= 0; i--) {
        siftDown(i);
    }
}

public int size() {
    return m_array.size();
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return m_array.isEmpty();
}

/**
 * O(log n)
 */
public PQItem<E> add(E data) {
    int s = size();
    PQItem<E> item = new PQItem(data, s);
    m_array.add(item);
    siftUp(s);
    return item;
}

/**
 * O(log n)
 */
public E removeFirst() {
    int size = size();
    if (size == 0) return null;
    if (size == 1) return m_array.remove(0).getData();

    int last = size - 1;
    // swap a[first] with a[last]
    PQItem<E> t = m_array.get(0); 
    E data = t.getData();
    set(0, m_array.get(last)); 
    set(last, t);
    // remove last
    m_array.remove(last);
    // heapify
    siftDown(0);
    return data;
}

public void clear() {
    m_array.clear();
}

public PQItem<E> getItem(int i) {
    return (i >= 0 && i < size()) ? m_array.get(i) : null;
}

public PQItem<E> getFirstItem() {
    return getItem(0);
}

public PQItem<E> getNextItem(PQItem<E> item) {
    if (item == null) return null;
    int index = item.getIndex() + 1;
    return (index < size()) ? m_array.get(index) : null;
}

/**
 * O(log n)
 */
public void updatePriority(PQItem<E> item) {
    int pos = item.getIndex();
    if (pos > 0) {
        // check heap condition at parent
        int par = (pos - 1)/2;
        if (m_array.get(par).compareTo(m_array.get(pos)) > 0) {
            siftUp(pos);
            return;
        }
    }
    int son = pos*2 + 1;
    if (son < size()) {
        // check heap condition at son
        if (m_array.get(pos).compareTo(m_array.get(son)) > 0) {
            siftDown(pos);
        }        
    }
}

private int set(int pos, PQItem<E> item) {
    int oldIndex = item.getIndex();
    item.setIndex(pos);
    m_array.set(pos, item);
    return oldIndex;
}

/**
 * sift down at position pos.
 * O(log n)
 */
private void siftDown(int pos) {
    final int end = size() - 1;
    int son = pos*2 + 1;

    while (son <= end) {
        // son ist der linke Sohn
        if (son < end) {
            // pos hat auch einen rechten Sohn
            if (m_array.get(son).compareTo(m_array.get(son + 1)) > 0) son++;
        }
        // son ist der grössere Sohn
        if (m_array.get(pos).compareTo(m_array.get(son)) > 0) {
            // swap a[pos] with a[son]
            PQItem<E> t = m_array.get(pos); 
            set(pos, m_array.get(son)); 
            set(son, t);
            pos = son;
            son = 2*pos + 1;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * sift up at position pos
 * O(log n)
 */
private void siftUp(int pos) {
    int par = (pos - 1)/2; // parent

    while(par >= 0) {
        if (m_array.get(par).compareTo(m_array.get(pos)) > 0) {
            // swap a[par] with a[pos]
            PQItem<E> t = m_array.get(par); 
            set(par, m_array.get(pos)); 
            set(pos, t);
            pos = par;
            par = (pos - 1)/2;
        } else {
            return;
        }            
    }
}
}
```

And here are three small examples of using the priority queue.

```
static void showMinHeap() {
    Integer[] values = { 7, 9, 6, 3, 5, 1, 2, 8, 4, 0};
    PQueue<Integer> pq = new PQueue<Integer>(Arrays.asList(values));

    int lev = 1, i = 0;
    PQueue.PQItem<Integer> item = pq.getFirstItem();
    while(item != null) {
        if (i == lev) {
            System.out.println();
            lev <<= 1;
            i = 0;
        }
        System.out.print(item.getData());
        System.out.print(' ');
        i++;
        item = pq.getNextItem(item);
    }    
    System.out.println();
}

static void heapSort() {
    Integer[] values = { 7, 9, 6, 3, 5, 1, 2, 8, 4, 0};
    PQueue<Integer> pq = new PQueue<Integer>(Arrays.asList(values));

    for(int i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(pq.removeFirst());
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}

static void testNodes() {
    class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        private int m_key;

        public Node(int k) { 
            m_key = k; 
        }

        public void updateKey() {
            m_key *= 2;
        }

        public int compareTo(Node v) {
            return (m_key == v.m_key) ? 0 : (m_key < v.m_key) ? -1 : 1;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(m_key);
        }
    }

    PQueue<Node> pq= new PQueue<Node>();
    Random rand = new Random(7777);
    final int size = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Node v = new Node(rand.nextInt(size));
        pq.add(v);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // change key and update priority
        PQueue.PQItem<Node> item = pq.getItem(rand.nextInt(pq.size()));
        item.getData().updateKey();
        pq.updatePriority(item);

        // remove and show first
        System.out.println(pq.removeFirst());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```