# How to remove maximum value from collection with 'O(log n)'_ time complexity?

Tags: java, collections, time-complexity

**I have a collection, I don't know which data structure to use yet for this.
I have two functions, add and remove.**

Both of the functions need to have similar complexities because they both are as frequently used.

It's either add function will be simple as O(1) and `removeMax` will be O(log n) or both o(1) or one of them log n and other o(n).

`removeMax` should remove the maximum value and return it, and should be able to use it multiple times, so the next time u call it it removes the next new max value.

Is there a way to do both with O(1) or atleast log n for remove?

Comment: The collection is, and must be, unsorted presumably?

Comment: @Michael yes it is unsorted, randomly

Comment: Are you looking for Fibonacci heap (or other kind of max heap)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap - O(1) insert, O(logn) delete (amortized of course)

Comment: Have a look at min-max heap. I believe that Priority queue uses one of these internally.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6273833/5515060), regarding the comment from @OndraK.

Comment: You can go fo red black data structure, [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) . 
In java `TreeMap` is implemented using the same datastructure , so It will give you log(n) for remove and adding. [Oracle docs for treemap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a sorted structure (such as `TreeSet`), both `add` and `remove` would require `O(logN)`.

If it's not sorted, `add` can be implemented in `O(1)` but `removeMax` would take `O(N)`, since you must check all the elements to find the maximum in an unsorted data structure.

Comment: Does TreeSet automatically sorts your collection? What is its a TreeSet<Variable> where Variable has getValue of integer, will it automatically know how to sort it?

Comment: @BenBeri Yes it does. If the element type of the TreeSet implements Comparable, that would define the ordering. Otherwise, you can supply a Comparator to the TreeSet constructor, which will define the ordering.

Comment: @BenBri you will get sorting at the time of insertion itself, So you don't have to worry about much at that time( It will take worst case scenario O(nlogn) for insertion instead of O(n) for you entire input for first time after that every insertion deletion followsO(logn). But please keep in mind that tree set will discard duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Max heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) are probably what you are looking for, their amortized complexity of *remove* operation is O(logn). [Fibonacci heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) (see this [great animation](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/JavascriptVisual/FibonacciHeap.html) to see how it works) seems like the data structure suitable for you, as it has O(1) for *insert* and all other operations. Sadly, it's implementation is not a part of standard Java libraries, but there's ton of implementations to be found (for instance see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273879/5362510) in the comment from @Lino).

[Guava's implementation of min-max heap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a data structure to do both add() and removeMax() in O(logn), then you just need a sorted array. For both removeMax() and add(), you can use binary search to find the target value. (for remove, you find the max value. for add, you find the biggest value smaller than the one you want to insert, and insert the value after it).Both time complexity is O(logn).