# Providing a comparator and collection to PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue, max-heap

I have a Map<Integer,Integer> freqMap where each value is the frequency of the key
Now I want to build a priorityQueue from this map

I was expecting a constructor like PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue(freqMap.keySet(), comparator);
But there is no such constructor.
Although I can construct it using a comparator and then add the keySet elements using addAll
But that will internally add elements one by one. In case I want to build a max heap out of the key set with comparator
as the values. I am not sure how can I do this.

**My Thoughts:**
one way could be that instead of Integer I make a custom class and wrap those integers and make the class implement a Comparable interface. Then when I pass that collection as a parameter to the priorityQueue constructor it should construct the priority Queue in O(n) time.
Whereas if I use the addAll method then probably it will take O(n log n) time. I am not sure though if my reasoning is correct here. It does seem a little complicated to just use a wrapper class that implements comparable for this tiny purpose.
The comparable will compare based on values so the key with the highest value should be on top.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How could a constructor sort the elements without sorting them? It still must add all items from the keyset using the comparator. There's really not any difference in using `new PriorityQueue();q.addAll(set);` vs `new PriorityQueue(set);`

Comment: The collection that is passed to the constructor should have a natural ordering or it should implement the `Comparable` Interface. Yeah you are right I think I worded it wrong. So the collection that is passed to the PQ should have a natural ordering otherwise we cannot avoid making an extra class and implementing `Comparable` That makes the code little longer though

Answer (score 0):

> construct the priority Queue in `O(n)` time

The only case when you can construct a new `PriorityQueue` in a linear time **O(n)** is when you already have another `PriorityQueue`.

In such case, the [copy-constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.PriorityQueue)) internally would invoke method `initFromPriorityQueue()` which would create a copy of the *underlying array* of the given `PriorityQueue` and would assign this copy to the *underlying array* of this (newly created) queue. The copying of elements would cost **O(n)**.

But when you have a collection that is **not** a `PriorityQueue` there's no way to ensure that the elements are ordered as required. That means that you need to enqueue them one-by-one, there's **no** workaround. For each element, it would have a cost of **O(log n)**. And the overall time complexity would be linear-logarithmic **O(n log n)**.

Here's a quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) regarding the time complexity of operations:

> ***Implementation note:***
>
> this implementation provides `O(log(n))` time for
> the **enqueuing** and **dequeuing** methods (`offer`, `poll`, `remove()` and `add`);

Since a *Binary Heap* (`PriorityQueue` *is an implementation of the Binary Heap data structure*) has the worst case time complexity **O(log n)** for inserting a new element, then inserting `n` would run in linear-logarithmic time.

Regarding the mechanism behind `addAll()`, as in many other collections it delegates to the method `add()` which a logarithmic worst case time complexity (*see the implementation note quoted above*).

**Note**

- All the information provided above is relevant for the [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class from the JDK, which is implemented as a *Binary Heap* (don't confuse this class with the *Priority queue data structure*).
- There are many ways to implement Heap data structure. And some of them like [Fibonacci Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) have amortized **O(1)** time complexity for insertion, which allows populating them with `n` elements in linear time **O(n)**. In such implementation would be included in the JDK in the future, then almost certainly it would not replace the current `PriorityQueue` implementation, but rather would be introduced as a new class (that's how Java is being developed since it's earlier days: new things come, almost nothing goes away).

Comment: But isn't constructing a Max-Heap take O(n) time? I read about complexity analysis in the `Intro to algorithm's book by Cormen` Which proves that building a Max-Heap takes O(n) time. So as per you doing `addAll(collection)` on an empty priority queue will take the exactly same time as `new PriorityQueue(collection)`?

Comment: @nicku I've addressed both of your questions in the updated answer. I can't check Cormen's book right now, but keep in mind that there are several classic implementations of the Heap data structure. And some of them like Fibonacci heap, or Pairing heap have constant time complexity for insertion (which would allow constructing a Heap in linear time). But they are not available as standard part of the JDK. You might try some third party libraries (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273833/is-there-a-standard-java-implementation-of-a-fibonacci-heap)), or implement your own one.

Comment: I checked the PriorityQueue.java file in SDK.  The `PriorityQueue(c)` constructor internally calls `initFromCollection(c)` which calls `heapify()` on top of this method is this description: `    `/**
     * Establishes the heap invariant (described above) in the entire tree,
     * assuming nothing about the order of the elements prior to the call.
     * This classic algorithm due to Floyd (1964) is known to be O(size).
     */ `It seems it indeed is O(n) But needs to explore more on this. Java online docs don't mention about `heapify`  probably because its a private method