# Java Priority Queue reordering when editing elements

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm for finding shortest paths using a priority queue. In each step of the algorithm, I remove the vertex with the shortest distance from the priority queue, and then update the distances for each of its neighbors in the priority queue. Now I read that a Priority Queue in Java won't reorder when you edit the elements in it (the elements that determine the ordering), so I tried to force it to reorder by inserting and removing a dummy vertex. But this doesn't seem to be working, and I'm stuck trying to figure it out.

This is the code for the vertex object and the comparator

```
class vertex {
    int v, d;
    public vertex(int num, int dis) {
        v=num;
        d=dis;
    }
}

class VertexComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare (Object a, Object b) {
        vertex v1 = (vertex)a;
        vertex v2 = (vertex)b;
        return v1.d-v2.d;
    }
 }
```

Here is then where I run the algorithm:

```
    int[] distances=new int[p];
    Comparator<vertex> comparator = new VertexComparator();
    PriorityQueue<vertex> queue = new PriorityQueue<vertex>(p, comparator);
    for(int i=0; i<p; i++) {
        if(i!=v) {
            distances[i]=MAX;
        }
        else {
            distances[i]=0;
        }
        queue.add(new vertex(i, distances[i]));
    }
    // run dijkstra
    for(int i=0; i<p; i++) {
        vertex cur=queue.poll();
        Iterator itr = queue.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            vertex test = (vertex)(itr.next());
            if(graph[cur.v][test.v]!=-1) {
                test.d=Math.min(test.d, cur.d+graph[cur.v][test.v]);
                distances[test.v]=test.d;
            }
        }
        // force the PQ to resort by adding and then removing a dummy vertex
        vertex resort = new vertex(-1, -1);
        queue.add(resort);
        queue.remove(resort);
    }
```

I've run several text cases, and I know that the priority queue isn't reordering correctly each time I go through and update the distances for vertices, but I don't know why. Did I make an error somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Java PriorityQueue when its elements change priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871253/updating-java-priorityqueue-when-its-elements-change-priority)

Answer (score 28):

As you discovered, a priority queue does not resort all elements whenever an element is added or removed. Doing that would be too expensive (remember the n log n lower bound for comparison sort), while any reasonable priority queue implementation (including `PriorityQueue`) promises to add/remove nodes in O(log n).

In fact, it doesn't sort its elements at all (that's why its iterator can not promise to iterate elements in sorted order).

`PriorityQueue` does not offer an api to inform it about a changed node, as that would require it to provide efficient node lookup, which its underlying algorithm does not support. Implementing a priority queue that does is quite involved. The [Wikipedia article on PriorityQueues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Effect_of_different_data_structures) might be a good starting point for reading about that. I am not certain such an implementation would be faster, though.

A straightforward idea is to remove and then add the changed node. Do *not* do that as `remove()` takes O(n). Instead, insert another entry for the same node into the PriorityQueue, and ignore duplicates when polling the queue, i.e. do something like:

```
PriorityQueue<Step> queue = new PriorityQueue();

void findShortestPath(Node start) {
    start.distance = 0;
    queue.addAll(start.steps());

    Step step;
    while ((step = queue.poll()) != null) {
        Node node = step.target;
        if (!node.reached) {
            node.reached = true;
            node.distance = step.distance;
            queue.addAll(node.steps());
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: It is not advisable to change the priorities of elements in the PQ, hence the need to insert `Step`s instead of `Node`s.

Comment: Great, I had the same idea, but wouldn't that change the running time of the algorithm from O(m log n) to O(m log m). As the heap will now be containing duplicate elements almost equal to the number of edges in the graph O(m). I think this won't be the best solution.

Comment: Path finding graphs are typically planar, and therefore have a constant average number of neighbors. That is, the size of the PQ will increase by a constant factor, and its height by a constant offset. This should not affect the runtime much. On the other hand, to efficiently modify nodes requires the caller to have a handle to each node. In Java, this can only be done through an object reference, which requires the PriorityQueue to store a node object for every entry. This is turn take a constant factor more memory than a priority queue that encodes its structure using array indices.

Comment: Therefore, it's really quite murky which implementation would be faster.

Comment: This isn't the best solution in cases where  time complexity has to be maintained but  in other cases ,it's good enough rather than implementing your own or using some other ds.

Answer (score 5):

you will have to delete and re-insert each element which is editted. (the actual element, and not a dummy one!). so, every time you update `distances`, you need to remove and add the elements that were affected by the changed entree.

as far as I know, this is not unique to Java, but every priority queue which runs at O(logn) for all ops, have to work this way.

Comment: `remove(Object o)` doesn't have to be O(n). It's just the Java library use a naive O(n) method to locate the element to remove. If instead you use an indexing structure like a map to store the position of the element in your heap, you can do `remove` in O(log(n)).

Comment: remove(Object) take O(n), but remove() and add take O(log(N)) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 5):

The disadvantage of Java's `PriorityQueue` is that `remove(Object)` requires O(n) time, resulting in O(n) time if you want to update priorities by removing and adding elements again. It can be done in time O(log(n)) however. As I wasn't able to find a working implementation via Google, I tried implementing it myself (in Kotlin though, as I really prefer that language to Java) using `TreeSet`.
This seems to work, and should have O(log(n)) for adding/updating/removing (updating is done via `add`):

```
// update priority by adding element again (old occurrence is removed automatically)
class DynamicPriorityQueue<T>(isMaxQueue: Boolean = false) {

    private class MyComparator<A>(val queue: DynamicPriorityQueue<A>, isMaxQueue: Boolean) : Comparator<A> {
        val sign = if (isMaxQueue) -1 else 1

        override fun compare(o1: A, o2: A): Int {
            if (o1 == o2)
                return 0
            if (queue.priorities[o2]!! - queue.priorities[o1]!! < 0)
                return sign
            return -sign
        }

    }

    private val priorities = HashMap<T, Double>()
    private val treeSet = TreeSet<T>(MyComparator(this, isMaxQueue))

    val size: Int
        get() = treeSet.size

    fun isEmpty() = (size == 0)

    fun add(newElement: T, priority: Double) {
        if (newElement in priorities)
            treeSet.remove(newElement)
        priorities[newElement] = priority
        treeSet.add(newElement)
    }

    fun remove(element: T) {
        treeSet.remove(element)
        priorities.remove(element)
    }

    fun getPriorityOf(element: T): Double {
        return priorities[element]!!
    }


    fun first(): T = treeSet.first()
    fun poll(): T {
        val res = treeSet.pollFirst()
        priorities.remove(res)
        return res
    }

    fun pollWithPriority(): Pair<T, Double> {
        val res = treeSet.pollFirst()
        val priority = priorities[res]!!
        priorities.remove(res)
        return Pair(res, priority)
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use a treemap instead of treeset.

Comment: I don't think that this works.  A core feature of a priority queue is that it allows duplicates, and sets don't.  From what I can gather, you have tried to allow duplicates by treating entries as "not equal" unless their pointers match within your comparator.  I tried a similar implementation in pure Java and this strategy appeared to work, however, it occasionally failed to delete an element in the set if a distinct element with the same priority existed.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the search through the tree for the element to delete will occasionally go down the wrong branch when it is compared to an element with the same priority.  Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I don't think that TreeSets can be retrofitted to allow duplicates.

Comment: PQs do allow duplicates, but for this particular problem the specific intent is to not have duplicates -- hence the removing and reinserting.  If identifying the matching node is a problem, there may be an issue in your equals/hashcode/compareTo methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid updating items in the queue just marking each node as *visited=false* by default, and adding new items to the queue as you go.

Then pop a node from the queue and process it only if it was not visited before.

Dijkstra's algorithm guarantees that each node is visited only once, so even if you may have stale nodes down the queue you never really process them.

Also it's probably easier if you separate the algorithm internals from the graph data structure.

```
public void dijkstra(Node source) throws Exception{
    PriorityQueue q = new PriorityQueue();
    source.work.distance = 0;
    q.add(new DijkstraHeapItem(source));

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        Node n = ((DijkstraHeapItem)q.remove()).node;
        Work w = n.work;

        if(!w.visited){
            w.visited = true;

            Iterator<Edge> adiacents = n.getEdgesIterator();
            while(adiacents.hasNext()){
                Edge e = adiacents.next();
                if(e.weight<0) throw new Exception("Negative weight!!");
                Integer relaxed = e.weight + w.distance;

                Node t = e.to;
                if (t.work.previous == null || t.work.distance > relaxed){
                    t.work.distance = relaxed;
                    t.work.previous = n;
                    q.add(new DijkstraHeapItem(t));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand - if you .remove() a node from the queue, you will trigger a reorder of the queue, thus defeating the purpose of setting .visited = true ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you update the `distances` array, but not the corresponding entry in the `queue`. To update the appropriate objects in the queue, you need to remove and then add.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by dividing my process into timeSlots ( A time Scheduler will be just fine ) and Extending the native PriorityQueue. So I implement a notify method where the key of this method is the following code:

```
// If queue has one or less elements, then it shouldn't need an ordering
// procedure
if (size() > 1)
{
    // holds the current size, as during this process the size will
    // be vary
    int tmpSize = size();
    for (int i = 1; i < tmpSize; i++)
    {
        add(poll());
    }
}
```

I hope It helped.

Answer (score -1):

I implemented an adaptive MinHeap that supports reorderining (O(nlogn)) when objects' priority are updated, written in Python.

```
class Node:
    """
    Model an object in Heap.
    """

    def __init__(self, key, val, i=-1) -> None:
        self.key = key  # object ID
        self.val = val  # object priority
        self.i = i  # index in heap array


class AdaptiveMinHeap:
    """
    Heap for objects. Support reorderining when objects' priority are updated.
    """

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.hp = {0: Node(-1, -1, 0)}  # Use dict to simulate list (key as the index) to support efficient reordering.
        self.d = dict()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.hp)-1

    def _swap(self, anode, bnode):
        d = self.d
        anode.key, bnode.key = bnode.key, anode.key
        anode.val, bnode.val = bnode.val, anode.val
        d[anode.key] = anode
        d[bnode.key] = bnode

    def _swim(self, i):
        hp = self.hp
        while i//2 > 0 and hp[i].val < hp[i//2].val:
            self._swap(hp[i], hp[i//2])
            i = i//2

    def _sink(self, i):
        hp = self.hp
        while i*2 < len(hp):
            if i*2 + 1 >= len(hp) or hp[i*2+1].val >= hp[i*2].val:
                min_child = i*2
            else:
                min_child = i*2+1
            if hp[min_child].val < hp[i].val:
                self._swap(hp[min_child], hp[i])
            i = min_child

    def push(self, key, val):
        hp = self.hp
        d = self.d
        if key in d:
            self.remove(key)
        node = Node(key, val, len(hp))
        d[key] = node
        hp[node.i] = node
        self._swim(node.i)

    def pop(self):
        hp = self.hp
        if len(hp) > 1:
            return self.remove(hp[1].key)

    def remove(self, key):
        hp = self.hp
        d = self.d
        node = d[key]
        self._swap(hp[node.i], hp[len(hp)-1])
        hp.pop(len(hp)-1)
        self._sink(node.i)
        return d.pop(key)

hp = AdaptiveMinHeap()
hp.push(1, 40)
hp.push(4, 8900)
hp.push(2, 500)
hp.push(3, 1075)
hp.push(1, 1)
for _ in range(len(hp)):
    poped = hp.pop()
    print(poped.key, poped.val)
# 1
# 500
# 1075
# 8900
```