# Changing the priority of an element in a PriorityQueue

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I know that `PriorityQueue` automatically sorts the elements when `add()`ing one by using the objects' `compareTo()` method. Let's say I want to change the priority of an element in the queue at some point. How do I explicitly order the `PriorityQueue` to sort itself again, given that the priority of an element has changed?

Comment: Remove the element, change its priority value, re-add it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Priority Queue reordering when editing elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952660/java-priority-queue-reordering-when-editing-elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871253/updating-java-priorityqueue-when-its-elements-change-priority

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the object, change its priority, and re-add it to the queue.

My intuition is that the data structure doesn't normally watch the internal state of the objects and that it requires an add() or remove() operation to trigger a re-invocation of the comparator. A call to Collections.sort(), would also work, but you would have to transform the queue to a list and then back to a queue. This might make more sense if you change a lot of priorities at one time.

Better still, you might update n priorities, then add and remove the last one.

Comment: Is there really no other way?

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to remove, modify and add back your object. `PriorityQueue` doesn't update it's internal structure on read. Here's an implimentation of `peek()` for example:

```
public E peek() {
    if (size == 0)
        return null;
    return (E) queue[0];
}
```

As you could see doesn't check if elements order has been changed.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought too.