# Reheapify java.util.PriorityQueue after updating elements

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a PriorityQueue containing references to some objects. When I initially insert the elements into the priority queue the ordering is maintained by the data structure. Now after a remove operation I update some of the references which are being held by the priority queue. Ideally this requires a reheapify operation on the priority queue but as is obvious since I am modifying selected references externally a reheapify cannot be triggered. So what is the best way to ensure that I am able to get the advantage of a heap like fast extract max in the presence of modifications to arbitrary elements inside the queue? I see I need a better data structure?

To be more specific I need an implementation of something like a Fibonacci heap in Java.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
Is that available?

Comment: I have an implementation of a Fibonacci heap in Java if you're interested.  It's available online at http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=fibonacci-heap .  Hope it helps!

Comment: Even fibonacci heaps aren't resilient in the face of out-of-band changes to the weights of elements.  I think you need to remove an element before you modify it and reinsert it afterwards.

Comment: removing an arbitrary element from the heap will require O(n) heap construction I guess.

Comment: The problem I guess is that the PriorityQueue provides me a linear time remove operation. If the data structure was transparent enough I could externally maintain the index of all elements in the priority queue so I could implement the DECREASE-KEY operation in O(lg V) time. Does anyone see any other data structure that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Does noone have an idea how we could get the efficient implementation using Java Collections API?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871253/updating-java-priorityqueue-when-its-elements-change-priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own tree that allows duplicate elements instead of heap.
Easier though, you can use `TreeMap<PriorityKey, LinkedHashSet<Value>>`.
All operations are O(log priorityType):

- adding is `get(priority).add(value)`, if get returns null, `put(priority, new LinkedHashSet())`
- removing an arbitrary element is similar, except needs to remove the priority out of the map if the Set is empty.
- poll() is

--

```
Entry<PriorityKey, LinkedHashSet<Value>> e = map.firstEntry(); 
if (e==null) return null; 
Iterator<Value> i = e.getValue().iterator(); 
Value v = i.next(); //must always have at least one element.
i.remove(); 
if (!i.hasNext()) map.remove(e.getKey());
return v;
```

Still if you need to change the priority you have to remove and add the element.

Comment: OK ... so I would say that the PriorityQueue in Java neither implements the DecreaseKey operation nor provides a way for the user to implement it efficiently.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga, finding a key in heap is O(n), then you can remove/add which is (log N), again if you need to access a random element in the queue you'd be better off w/ a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a NavigableMap would suit your needs : easy identification of the "highest" or "lowest" element, fast insertion and access time, and you could update values easily.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html

TreeMap implements NavigableMap, and therefore provides the firstEntry/lastEntry methods, and many more.

Comment: you cant have duplicate elements in the map and it has to be sorted by priority. the solution of using a tree(map) involves mapping priority->collection. (what i posted)