# Dijkstra-Algorithm Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm supposed to implement Dijkstra for my school homework. I understand the algorithm itself and based my code on Wikipedia and some other sources, however I seem to have some kind of fault in it, since it basically doesn't terminate in my JUnit tests.

Code:

```
@Override
public void populateDijkstraFrom(Node startNode) {

    this.resetState();
    // TODO: Your populateDijkstraFrom implementation here

    // You can use this implementation of a priority queue.
    // Nodes that are added to the queue are automatically sorted by distance 
    // because we overwrote Node.compareTo()


    if(startNode == null){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    for (Node n : nodes.values()){
        if(n != startNode){
        n.predecessor=null;
        n.distance=Integer.MAX_VALUE;                           //set distance of each node to maxvalue
        }
    }

    PriorityQueue<Node> distanceQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
    startNode.predecessor=null;
    startNode.distance=0;                                      //set distance of startnode to 0
    distanceQueue.add(startNode);                             //add startnode to the PQ

    while (!distanceQueue.isEmpty()){
        Node current = distanceQueue.poll();                    // get headelement of PQ
        current.status=2;
        for(Node i : current.getAdjacentNodes()){
            int weight = current.getWeight(i);
            int distancethroughcurrent = current.distance + weight;

            if(distancethroughcurrent < i.distance){
                i.distance = distancethroughcurrent;
                i.predecessor = current;
                distanceQueue.add(i);
                i.status=1;
            }
        }
    }
    // clean up
    this.clearMarks();
    }
```

in addition the calculation of the shortest path, we are also supposed to write a method, that finds this path by using the method above and returns it in a list:

```
@Override
public List<Node> getShortestPathDijkstra(int startNodeID, int targetNodeID) {
    return getShortestPathDijkstra(nodes.get(startNodeID), nodes.get(targetNodeID));
}

/**
 * Calculates a List of Node indices that describe the shortet path from
 * start node to target node. The Dijkstra-Algorithmn is used for
 * calculation.
 * 
 * @param targetNodeIndex
 *            the index of the target node, as returned by addNode()
 * @return the list of nodes, or null if no path exists
 */
@Override
public List<Node> getShortestPathDijkstra(Node startNode, Node targetNode) {
    // NOTE: you have to run populateDijkstraFrom first before you can read
    // out the shortest path
    LinkedList<Node> DijkstraList = new LinkedList<Node>();
    if(startNode == null || targetNode == null){
        throw new RuntimeException();              //check if either node is null
    }
    populateDijkstraFrom(startNode);
    Stack <Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    while(targetNode.predecessor != null){
        stack.push(targetNode);
        targetNode = targetNode.predecessor;
    }
    stack.push(startNode);

    while (!stack.isEmpty()){
        Node item = stack.pop();
        DijkstraList.add(item);
    }


    //This line stops program execution until a key is pressed
    //stopExecutionUntilSignal();

    //Return an empty list. Replace this line by the shortest path!

    return DijkstraList;
}
```

EDIT: here a testcase that doesn't run through:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class DijkstraTest {

private DiGraph g1;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // read graph from file
    try {
        g1 = GraphIO.loadGraph("tests/testgraphen/graphDijkstra.txt");
        g1.setShowSteps(true);

        VisualGraph v = new VisualGraph(g1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void testDijkstraShortestPath() {

    // fill distance and predecessor values
    g1.populateDijkstraFrom(0);

    // expected list
    LinkedList<Integer> expect = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    expect.addFirst(3);
    expect.addFirst(2);
    expect.addFirst(1);
    expect.addFirst(0);

    // test actual getShortestPath from 0 to 3
    List<Node> actualNodes = g1.getShortestPathDijkstra(0, 3);

    assertEquals(
            "getShortestPath didn't find the path with the right number of nodes",
            actualNodes.size(), expect.size());

    LinkedList<Integer> actual = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (Node n : actualNodes) {
        actual.addLast(n.getID());
    }

    assertEquals("getShortestPath didn't return the shortest path",
            actual.toString(), expect.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the JUnit test case that fails for your algorithm. This would help save us time and narrow down a bit...

Comment: whoops, forgot! added it.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know the output of that test when it fails.

Comment: it doesn't even finish, like i said in my post :( it just keeps running until i abort it

Comment: figured out why it doesn't finish. totally forgot to comment out the stopExecutionUntilSignal(); line! it was meant to help us with the debugging. after commenting that out, i get the error: getshortestpath didn't find the path with the right number of nodes: expected <3> but was <4>

Comment: How comes priority queue sorts nodes in right order? I don't think you have implemented stable (!) comparator in Node class. If you implemented one relying on this.distance, it's not stable (so it's wrong to use one in priorityQueue). http://stackoverflow.com/q/1871253/6809386