# When is a PriorityQueue prioritised?

Tags: java, android, path-finding

I am implementing a version of the A*-pathfinding algorithm for Android. I use a PriorityQueue to manage my `openList`.

In some cases I update the *prioritizing*-attribute of one of the queue's entries. If I call `remove()`, to get the *head*-Object on the updated queue, expecting to get the *updated* entry, I get wrong results. It seems not to prioritize the updated queue correctly.

The only solution I found was to remove the specific entry, update the value and put it back in like so:

```
openList.remove(objectToBeUpdated);
objectToBeUpdated.setPriorityAttribute(newValue);
openList.add(objectToBeUpdated);
```

It seems like the queue does prioritize when adding objects, not by polling/removing them?

Is there another way than removing and adding it again? Its such a dirty solution, i think. Or is this just the PriorityQueue's behaviour and I have to deal with it?

Comment: You effectively want to rebuild the entire structure every time it is read? This sounds awfully inefficient.

Comment: As far as I'm aware Java's implementation of `PriorityQueue` does not change the priority if the object is modified whilst currently in the queue.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Is there a huge difference between "sorting on input" and "sorting on remove()"?

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1871303/1646982 you have to re-insert the object.

Comment: @Dario Yes, an `O(n log n)` operation every call to `remove()` or an `O(n)` (or perhaps even `O(log n)` if backed by a binary tree) operation on every `add()` call.