# Sorting a PriorityQueue with Queue Size

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Is it possible to implement a PQ so it sorts the PQ by the size of the Queue of Customers?

```
private PriorityQueue<Queue<Customer>> queue = new PriorityQueuee<Queue<Customer>>();
```

Comment: Will the length of each inner queue change after being placed within the PriorityQueue? If so, you are likely heading for deep trouble.

Comment: Yea, i'll be adding to each inner queue during run time. Is that an issue?

Comment: I believe that if is the case, then you must remove and reinsert the items into the queue each time the sorting property of the item changes.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871253/updating-java-priorityqueue-when-its-elements-change-priority) for more on this issue.

Comment: Yea I ended up just removing and reinserting.